# Using relative numbering for tables and figures

Tags: writing, graphics, writing-style

I'm producing documentation for an A-Level Computing project. Throughout my project I've been numbering my tables and figures relative to the chapter and section they're contained in. So for example, instead of doing:

> ## 2. Design
>
> ...
>
> ### 2.3. Object analysis
>
> **Figure 4 - diagram of objects**

I've done:

> ## 2. Design
>
> ...
>
> ### 2.3. Object analysis
>
> **Figure 2.3.1. - diagram of objects**

I'd like to know if the latter style of numbering is considered bad practice. Should my figures instead always be absolutely numbered? Or should I use absolute numbering and restart the number for each section? I'm not required to conform to an academic style, so this is more for myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your school does not have a specific scheme in place for such reports, then you are free to use whatever scheme you feel most logically identifies things. Personally, I prefer the longer style of numbering, because it helps me to orient myself through a large document. It's certainly not bad practice, although it's somewhat unusual to "drill down" all the way to the subsection level.

Comment: Depends on how many figures are in each subsection. If all subsections are very figure-dense...